# Caption label font: will sc and bf conflict with each other?

Tags: tables, fonts, captions

I want both bold and small capital effect for my table caption label. Could anybody tell me what's wrong with my code? Why doesn't it work? Thanks

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={scriptsize,bf,sc},textfont={it,scriptsize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Tables Testing}
\begin{table}[htdp]
\caption{default}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
column A & column B \\ \hline
line1 & line2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{default}
\end{table}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the log file you'll find: ``LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/bx/sc' undefined using `T1/cmss/bx/n' instead``: this means the font does not have bold small caps. Indeed, if you use a font that has them (e.g. [`libertine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine) you'll see that the caption setup works as it is supposed to.

Comment: `\usepackage{libertine}` I'm not sure it's a font well suited for presentations, though. Maybe Helvetica (`\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}`)? BTW you may be interested in http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

Comment: I don't think this is at all unclear. It is just answered in the comments. If it is not a duplicate, perhaps @cgnieder could write an answer?

Comment: @cfr My answer no longer holds: with an up to date TL14 the example gives `Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already redefined by a document class or package which is unknown to the caption package. See the caption package documentation for explanation.`

Comment: @cgnieder Good to know. In that case, I think it is not unclear and not answered in the comments ;).

Answer (score 4):

As the warning message now reports, `caption` does not know about what `beamer` is doing, and as a result, gives up.

But `beamer` already has hooks to the caption label/text fonts that we can use directly to achieve the same result:

```
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize,shape=\itshape}
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{size=\scriptsize,shape=\scshape,series=\bfseries}
```

I put the changes inside `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{<...>}` from `etoolbox` to keep the changes local to tables only; the captions for figures are unaffected, as illustrated below.

Of course, we need a font that has all the required combinations; I chose `libertine` as suggested in the comments, but you may have a better idea of what you want to use.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
}

\usepackage{libertine} % so that we have all the required fonts
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % for patching the table environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{% change the caption fonts only inside table (figure unaffected)
  \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize,shape=\itshape}
  \setbeamerfont{caption name}{size=\scriptsize,shape=\scshape,series=\bfseries}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Tables Testing}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{default}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
column A & column B \\ \hline
line1 & line2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{default}
\end{table}%
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Test figure.
  \caption{Test figure caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]